# 'Save' sheet section which will be displayed again once data validation shows the 'saved' section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So in my sheet is a data validation which gets items of a range.
Upon selection an item next to the data validation there are Unique categories which are written down by `=arrayformula`.
I want to input specific data for each unique categorie. Upon changing the item from the data validation I want the data of these categories to be saved. This can happen on another sheet which is going to be hidden. Not able to do that with `=arrayformula`, since it will remove the data upon changing the categories.

Link to the mentioned spreadsheet so u could see it yourself (names etc changed) 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d7Rz56FlgClCHPkT4f9LD-MzoyPQ-GlCY1uE9nOLY5I/edit?usp=sharing

Hope I was able to explain it a little bit. Thanks for any help

Comment: what you need is a script which will archive columns from sheet1 into sheet2

Comment: I see, i´ll try that. Thanks a lot.